# Use C# to solve simply quadratic optimization in practice accord.net

Tags: c#, optimization

[image]

To solve such `quadratic programming` problem(`mean-variance portfolio`), I want to use `Microsoft.SolverFoundation` in `C#`, but the introduction in

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff759370(v=vs.93).aspx

is too abstract to understand, can any one give me a specific example or other free libaray I can easily handle?

Here I use `accord.net`

```
// Declare symbol variables
double x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

// Create the function to be optimized
var f = new QuadraticObjectiveFunction(() => x * x - 2 * x * y + 3 * y * y + z * z - 4 * x - 5 * y - z);

// Create some constraints for the solution
var constraints = new List<LinearConstraint>();
constraints.Add(new LinearConstraint(f, () => 6 * x - 7 * y <= 8));
constraints.Add(new LinearConstraint(f, () => 9 * x + 1 * y <= 11));
constraints.Add(new LinearConstraint(f, () => 9 * x - y <= 11));
constraints.Add(new LinearConstraint(f, () => -z - y == 12));

// Create the Quadratic Programming solver
GoldfarbIdnani solver = new GoldfarbIdnani(f, constraints);

// Minimize the function
bool success = solver.Minimize();

double value = solver.Value;
double[] solutions = solver.Solution;
```

The left question is

1. how to write x, y, z as a vector x = (x_1, x_2, ... , x_n) since I have a lot of variables(Surely write objective function as the form of matrix f = xMx')?
2. Can I use the `linq query` in for the `vector` in `accord.net`

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.SolverFoundation is deprecated.

I would suggest to use Accord.Net if you need to do it in C#.

Comment: could you give some example for this library, I  really hurry to solve this problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://github.com/accord-net/framework/wiki/Sample-applications#quadratic-programming-qp-solver

Comment: very helpful! and some questions left, pls see the update.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help any further on this matter.  I suggest you create a new question tagged with Accord.Net and expand your question some.

Answer (score -1):

you can find something in the link below:
http://crsouza.com/2012/04/05/quadratic-programming-in-c/

The part "Manually specifying the QP matrix" will be useful

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your answer to include the important information instead of a link. Thanks!